# Python can't print variable in batch language

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I want to print batch variable using `echo` in python.

```
from os import system

def CMD(cmd): # this is for do many stuff in one function
    for a in range(0, len(cmd)):
        system(cmd[a])

CMD(["ECHO Hello World!",
     "SET var=Hi!",
     "ECHO %var%", # here i want to print "Hi!" but it prints %var%
     "PAUSE"])
```

Output:

```
%var% # i want to get variable: "Hi!"
```

How do I success this?

Comment: no knowledge about phyton here, but it looks as if you are executing each line in a separate `cmd` session. So you execute `system(set var=Hi!)` then the process ends and the next command is executed in a new `cmd`, which isn't aware what happened in the previous session (which is lost forever)

Comment: Instead of `,` just put the command in one long string seperated by `&`s and  put `/k` or `/c` as your first argument